# How to fix " Unexpected token < " error in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm developing a `nodejs` logger app , the problem is that when i want to retrieve data to show them in a table ,this error occurs :

> <% include('header'); -%>
>   ^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

My code is as follows :

**errorcontroller** :

```
 const controller = require('app/http/controllers/controller');
 const errors = require('resource/views/error.ejs');
 var error = require('app/models/error');
 var logs ;

 class errorController extends controller {
    show(req,res){
         error.find({})
             .then(res.render(errors, { results : results }))
   }
  }

   module.exports = new errorController();
```

**error.ejs**

```
<% include('header'); %>


<div class="list-group">
  <% results.forEach((results) => { %>
    <a href="/geterrors %>" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= results.cid %></h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= results.stacktrace %></p>
    </a>
  <% }) %>
</div>

<% include('footer'); %>
```

is there any problem with my `controller` ? or the `ejs` syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js cannot `require` a `ejs` file.

Put `error.ejs` under `./views` directory, and call `res.render` as follow:

```js
res.render('error.ejs', {results: results})
```

See the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) about `res.render`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you write code in the wrong way it should be something like

```
class errorController extends controller {
    show(req,res){
         error.find({})
             .then(()=>res.render('error.ejs', {results: results}))
   }
  }
```